# swift encrypt text using a public key

Tags: swift, swift2

Say I have a public key stored in a string:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcoczQFi0PL/NlQQIlSBeRY6Rg
71nihmGP845weN/3HeAGPq+iLlBSClDRR3J17X1sc+fOXmB1Jz+d0A5pDidciaCP
j1p0dqQz1fhNvGm4+TrFwABlKwgFsVhI1McCSQjIrJSuzKSFc33E1xewl7vhfL5QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

What is the easiest way to take this key and encrypt some text with it? What libraries should I be using? An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider http://cocoapods.org/pods/ObjectivePGP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils

Seems to be able to do everything I need.